# Select Column values from different Table issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I the `employee` table i am having a Column named `Department` which stores data in numerical format. I want this Department actual values which are in different table named `combovalues`. So here is the query.

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.code, 
       (SELECT combovalue 
        FROM   dbo.combovalues 
        WHERE  id = e.department) AS [DEPARTMENT] 
FROM   dbo.employee e 
WHERE  e.department = 'Admin'
```

Now i want to query Department according to actual values but this gives me error :-

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Admin' to data
>   type int.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of your error is that the `DEPARTMENT` alias you compute using a correlated subquery is not available in the `WHERE` clause.  But I would just write your query as a join to get around this problem:

```
SELECT
    e.id, 
    e.code, 
    COALESCE(c.combovalue, 'NA') AS combovalue
FROM dbo.employee e
LEFT JOIN dbo.combovalues c
    ON c.id = e.department AND c.combovalue = 'Admin';
```

Note that you *could* make your current approach work by subquerying your current query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        e.id, 
        e.code, 
        (SELECT combovalue FROM dbo.combovalues WHERE id = e.department) department
    FROM dbo.employee e 
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE department = 'Admin';
```

But this is verbose, and not necessary since a join is the better way to go.

Comment: Do LEFT JOIN, just in case there's no combovalues match.

Answer (score 0):

Try inner join:

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.code FROM   dbo.employee e 
inner join  dbo.combovalues c
        on  c.id = e.department
WHERE  c.combovalue = 'Admin'
```

Comment: Do LEFT JOIN, just in case there's no combovalues match.